# how to check all fields are filled with 2nd level fields from some drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, list, field

Anyone have idea with how to check all fields are filled with 2nd level fields from some drop-down list ? I have tried a method from internet but it checking all the fields ,including the hidden fields. How to check the fields which are visible ?

This is my code:

All form fields are required.

```
<form id="FORM"  name="frmname" action="./../ScheduleServlet" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <table style="width: 600px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px"><label for="jobName">Job Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="jobName" id="jobName"
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="option0" >
            <td><label for="ProfileName">Profile Name</label></td>

                <td><select id="ProfileName" name="ProfileName">    
                <option >...Choose Profile Name...</option>
            <% 
            try{
                OverlayManager overlayMgr = new OverlayManager();
                ArrayList<OverlayDTO> currentList = overlayMgr.findAllOverlay();
                String name = "";
                for(int i = 0; i<currentList.size(); i++)
                {
                    name = currentList.get(i).getProfileName();
                    System.out.println("Here is name : "+name);
                        %>
                        <option ><%=name%></option>
                    <% }




            }        

                        catch(Exception e)

                        {

                            out.println("Error" +e);

                        }

            %>




                </select></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="ScheduleType">Scheduled Type</label></td>
                <td><select id="ScheduleType" name="ScheduleType">
                        <option value="0">---Choose a type---</option>
                        <option value="1">Custom (Adhoc / Run Once)</option>
                        <option value="2">Hourly</option>
                        <option value="3">Daily</option>
                        <option value="4">Weekly</option>
                        <option value="5">Monthly</option>

                </select></td>

            </tr>



            <tr id="option1" style="display: none;">
                <td><label for="hour">Hour</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="hour" id="hour" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
            </tr>



            <tr id="option3" style="display: none;">
                <td><label for="Weekly">Weekly</label></td>
                <td><select id="dayofWeek" name="dayofWeek">
                        <option value="1">Monday</option>
                        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                        <option value="5">Friday</option>
                        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
                        <option value="7">Sunday</option>
                </select></td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="option4" style="display: none;">
                <td><label for="Monthly">Monthly</label></td>
                <td><select id="dateofMonth" name="dateofMonth">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="LD">Last Day</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="option5" style="display: none;">
                <td><label for="Adhoc">Adhoc</label></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" id="datetext" name="datetext"  />
                </td>

                <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date"  />
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="scheduleTime">Scheduled Time</label></td>
                <td>
                <div id="container">
                <div class="example">
                <input id="myPicker" class="time" type="text" style=" height : 22px;"/></div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td><label for="retry">Retry</label></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="retry" id="retry" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="sRemarks">Remarks</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sRemarks" id="sRemarks" value=""
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div data-role="controlgroup" id="ScheduleButtons"
            data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" align="center"
            style="width: 500px">

            <a href="#" onClick="createSchedule()" data-role="button" data-icon="check"
                style="width: 100px">Save </a>
                 <a href="#" onClick="closewindow()" data-role="button" 
                data-icon="delete" style="width: 100px">Cancel </a>
        </div>

    </fieldset>



</form>

<script>
$(function() {

$("#myPicker").timepicker();});

</script>


<script>


function checkDate(ExpDate){
    // define date string to test 
    var ExpiryDate = document.getElementById(ExpDate).value;
    // check date and print message 
    if (isDate(ExpiryDate)) {
 //     alert('OK');
    }
    else {
        alert('invalidDateErr');
        if(ExpDate=="datepicker1"){
            document.myform.optthree1.value = "";       
        }
        else{
            document.myform.optthree2.value = "";
        }
    }          
}   

document.getElementById('ScheduleType').onchange = function(){
if (this.value == '2') {
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option5').style.display = "none";
}else if (this.value == '4') {
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display = "";
     document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option5').style.display = "none";
}
else if (this.value == '5') {
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option5').style.display = "none";
}
else if (this.value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('option5').style.display = "";
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display = "none";
}
else  {
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option3').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option4').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option5').style.display = "none";
}};</script><script type="text/javascript">
function createSchedule() 
{
 var incomplete = $('FORM :input').filter(function() {
     return $(this).val() == '';
 });
//if incomplete contains any elements, the form has not been filled 
if(incomplete.length) {
alert('please fill out the form');
//to prevent submission of the form
 return false;
 }
else{

    var sName = document.getElementById("jobName").value;
    //var sProfile = document.getElementById("sProfileName").value;

    var h = document.getElementById("ProfileName");
    var sProfile = h.options[h.selectedIndex].value;

    var hour = document.getElementById("hour").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var time = document.getElementById("myPicker").value;
    var retry = document.getElementById("retry").value;
    var sRemarks = document.getElementById("sRemarks").value;


    var g = document.getElementById("ScheduleType");
    var sTypeID = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;


    var f = document.getElementById("dayofWeek");
    var dayofWeek = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;

    var e = document.getElementById("dateofMonth");
    var dateofMonth = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //alert('here!!!'+dateofMonth);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        url: "./../ScheduleServlet",
        data: {ActionType:"1",sName:sName,sProfile:sProfile,sTypeID:sTypeID,hour:hour,dayofWeek:dayofWeek,dateofMonth:dateofMonth,date:date,time:time,retry:retry,sRemarks:sRemarks},
        success: function(TokenData){
        //  alert("response data: "+TokenData);
            if(TokenData != null){
                returnValue = TokenData;
                alert("Successfully Saved!");
                url: "./../ScheduleServlet",
                window.opener.location.reload(false);
                window.close();
            }                   
        }
      });   

    //alert("data is :"+returnValue);
        return returnValue; 
 }  
  }

function closewindow(){
    var ans = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
     if(ans){
            window.close();
       }


 }
```